# Chained dropdown list. Issue with "this.value"- jquery, django

Tags: jquery, django

I trying to develop simple chained 2 steps drop down list. I have made fist step which works fine. I have trouble with second step.
I using jquery to filter list based on what has changed. In first step "this.value" which is part of filter gets proper value, list is filtered.

I second step, if I understand correctly "this.value" should be changed to value of option that has been chosen by user but it remains same as in first step.

I looking for a tip how to solve that.

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
        var $clientvar = $("#client");
        var $clientssubvar = $("#clientssub");
        var $clientssubwvar = $("#clientssubw");

       /*first step*/
        var $options = $clientssubvar.find('option');
            $clientvar.on('change', function()
            {
                $clientssubvar.html($options.filter('[value="'+this.value+'"]'));
            });


       /*second step*/
        var $options1 = $clientssubwvar.find('option');
            $clientssubvar.on('change', function()
            {
                $clientssubwvar.html($options1.filter('[value="'+this.value+'"]'));
            }).trigger('change');

});
```

HTML

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='row py-5'>
    <select name ="client" id="client" class="form-control">
      <option value="" disabled selected="true">wybierz klienta</option>
      {% for client in clients %}
      <option value="{{ client.nazwa }}">{{ client }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class='row py-5'>
    <select name ="clientssub" id="clientssub" class="form-control">
      <option value="" disabled selected="true">wybierz filię</option>
      {% for clientssub in clientssub %}
      <option value="{{ clientssub.firma }}">{{ clientssub }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class='row py-5'>
    <select name ="clientssubw" id="clientssubw" class="form-control">
      <option value="" disabled selected="true">wybierz przedstawicila</option>
      {% for clientssubw in clientssubw %}
      <option value="{{ clientssubw.filia }}">{{ clientssubw }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
  </div>


  <div class='row py-5'>
    <input type="text" id="textFieldTextJQ" class="form-control" placeholder="get value on option select">
  </div>
</div>
```

views.py

```
def wypozycz_tester(request, numer_seryjny):
    item = get_object_or_404(Tester, numer_seryjny=numer_seryjny)
    numer = item.numer_seryjny
    clients = Firma.objects.all()
    clientssub = Filia.objects.all()
    clientssubw = Phandlowy.objects.all()
    context = {
        'clients': clients,
        'clientssub': clientssub,
        'clientssubw': clientssubw

    }
    return render(request, 'wypozycz.html', context)
```

models.py

```
class Firma(models.Model):
    nazwa = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True)
    ulica = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    miejscowosc = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    kod_pocztowy = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    history = HistoricalRecords()
    dhandlowiec = models.ForeignKey(DHandlowiec, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Klienci"


    def __str__(self):
        return self.nazwa


class Filia(models.Model):
    nazwa = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True)
    ulica = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    miejscowosc = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    kod_pocztowy = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    firma = models.ForeignKey(Firma, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    history = HistoricalRecords()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.nazwa


class Phandlowy(models.Model):
    imie = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    nazwisko = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField()
    telefon = models.IntegerField()
    filia = models.ForeignKey(Filia, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    history = HistoricalRecords()


    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Siły sprzdażowe - Klient"


    def __str__(self):
        return self.imie+" "+self.nazwisko
```

Comment: You want if first dropdown change then 2nd and 3rd dropdown should also show that change ?

Comment: Thank you for looking at this issue. I have already solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I have been referring to value which was needed for first step to work.
Modified jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
        var $clientvar = $("#client");
        var $clientssubvar = $("#clientssub");
        var $clientssubwvar = $("#clientssubw");

        var $options = $clientssubvar.find('option');
            $clientvar.on('change', function()
            {
              console.log(this);
                $clientssubvar.html($options.filter('[value="'+this.value+'"]'));
            }).trigger('change');

        var $options1 = $clientssubwvar.find('option');
            $clientssubvar.on('click', function()
            {
              console.log($("#clientssub option:selected").text());
              console.log($clientssubwvar.html())
                $clientssubwvar.html($options1.filter('[value="'+$("#clientssub option:selected").text()+'"]'));
            }).trigger('change');

});
```